# Alternative to env that accepts arguments

Tags: bash, shell, sh

It is commonly known that `env` does not allow passing of arguments - at least not reliably. There are various workarounds described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e), but they felt to hacky and unreadable to me. That's why I developed an alternative, `ex`.

**ex:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# save the string given in the sheband line
shebang_line="$1"

# remove it from $@
shift

# execute 
# not quoting shebang_line is intentional
eval $(echo $shebang_line "$@")
```

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ex python "-i"
# quoting the arguments is possible
import sys

print('hello', sys.argv)
```

It works surprisingly well, but I don't like the eval-echo thing. I tried experimenting with arrays, but haven't found a solution. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend calling your program `ex`.  That name has a well established meaning in the Unix world as the name of a [text-editing tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29).

Comment: I have never heard of this before, thank you for pointing that out.